# ExtJS Tab panel autoLoad not executing the scripts

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I have a tab panel having three tabs on it and they are using a loader to load different tab contents. All are having autoLoad but only first tab content is shown and other tabs are empty. But i found that all the ajax request are done in firebug but the content won't render.
Here is the code snippet..

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    height: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    id:'InstrumentEditWindow_tabpanel',
    items: [
      {
          title: 'Instrument details',
          id:'InstrumentEditWindow_instrumentTab',
          loader: {
                loadMask:true,
                url: '?r=instrument',
                single:true,
                autoShow: true,
                renderer: 'html',
                method:'GET',
                autoLoad: true,
                scripts: true
          },
          height:270 
      }, 
      {
          title: 'Weighbridge details',
          id:'InstrumentEditWindow_weighbridgeTab',
          loader: {
                loadMask:true,
                url: '?r=instrument/Default/weighbridge',
                renderer: 'html',
                autoShow: true,
                method:'GET',
                single:true,
                autoLoad: true,
                scripts: true
           },
           height:270                                        
       },
       {
           title: 'Package details',
           id:'InstrumentEditWindow_packageTab',
           loader: {
                 loadMask:true,
                 url: '?r=instrument/Default/package',
                 renderer: 'html',
                 method:'GET',
                 autoShow: true,
                 single:true,
                 autoLoad: true,
                 scripts: true
            },
            height:270         
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Do your ajax calls appear all at once when the Panel is loaded or they only show up as you click on the tabs?